# You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream, django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to read request body using django but, it throws an error:

> **You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream**

Here is my code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_profile(request):
    """
       
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:

            # Validate
            payload = json.loads(request.body)
            # get files
            profile_pic = request.FILES.get('profile_pic')

            user_data = util.update_profile(obj_common, user_id, payload,profile_pic)

            return user_data
```

I have seen many answer on the stackoverflow, They advice me to replace request.body with request.data.

but when it tried i got another error

> **{AttributeError}'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'**

Comment: `request.data` is only available when you're using Django REST framework.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `request.POST` is being processed somewhere before calling this function. Try searching for it